Knex joining multiple tables with inner and left joins
I have been struggling with this for last couple days. can someone help?
Here is my sql
SELECT
  rd.id,
  rd.registration_id,
  rd.retreat_detail_id,
  rd.retreat_user_detail_id,
  rd.seva_remarks,
  rd.can_do_seva,
  rd.preassigned_seva,
  rd.no_heavy_lifting,
  rd.no_repetitive_motion,
  rd.sitting_seva,  
  concat(ru.first_name, ' ', ru.last_name) as name,
  rd.total_seva_mins_allocated, 
  x.currently_assigned
from 
  registration_detail rd 
  inner join registration r on rd.registration_id = r.id AND rd.status <> "CANCELLED" AND r.status <> "CANCELLED" 
  inner join retreat_user_detail ru on rd.retreat_user_detail_id = ru.id 
  inner join retreat_detail rdt on rdt.retreat_id = 1 AND rd.retreat_detail_id = rdt.id
  left join (
    select 
      usa.reg_detail_id, 
      group_concat(sd.day_number, "\t" , sd.name, " ", sd.start_time, " ", sd.end_time, "\n") as currently_assigned 
    from 
      seva_detail sd 
    inner join user_seva_allocation usa on usa.seva_detail_id = sd.id group by usa.reg_detail_id ) x on x.reg_detail_id = rd.id
where 
  rd.registration_id = 1430; 

I was able to string together a couple inner joins but have not been able to match the sql once I add the left join requirements...

Please include your knex code as well so we can see how you're mapping the SQL to knex.
